# React native release version cant connect to internet

Tags: react-native

This is a strange problem, and I have not encountered it before. All accesses are checked and the debug version works perfectly without problems. Manifest internet access its ok . only and only after release react native app cant access internet with fetch .

Comment: Are you using a proxy?

Comment: no proxy ......

Comment: iOS, Android, or both?

Comment: android.........

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use SSL (`https` protocol) for API/URL. Http is only for debugging your application on the emulator, but in a release mode, you must use `https` for URLs.

Comment: The protocol limit is for ios only.

Comment: I tested on Android 9. So I'll test on Android 7

Comment: @bnnoor, anything?

Answer (score 1):

Put `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` in your android manifest file